# 連想配列をループで取り出した(PHP)

Tags: php, cakephp

下記の配列を`foreach`で取り出したのですが、どのようなコードを書けばいいですか？
$iの部分を0から順に取り出したいです。

```
<?php foreach ($price as $p): ?>
     <?php echo $p[$i][0]['SUM(price)']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>


array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'SUM(price)' => '13'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'SUM(price)' => '5'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'SUM(price)' => '23'
        )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'SUM(price)' => '100'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらでどうでしょうか？
ただ……記述されていますコードで気になるのは
`as`の後の変数は`$p==$price[$i]`です。添え字は要りません。
添え字を使う必要性があるのでしたら`foreach ($array as $key=>$val):`で
必要性が無いのであれば`foreach ($array as $val):`で大丈夫だと思います。

```
<?php foreach ($price as $i=>$p): ?>
     <?php echo $p[0]['SUM(price)']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```